# xpath: Obtaining a value of the parent node for each child node

Tags: xml, xpath

Given this XML:

```
<child id="1"  name="alpha" >Some Text</child
<child id="2"  name="beta" > 
  <grandchild id="2.1"></grandchild> 
  <grandchild id="2.2"></grandchild> 
</child> 
<child id="3"  name="gamma"  mark="yes" > 
  <grandchild id="3.1"  name="gamma-alpha"> </grandchild> 
  <grandchild id="3.2"  name="gamma-beta" ></grandchild> 
</child>
```

There are 4 grandchild nodes, and i'd like to obtain all of their parents (which happen to be the "child" nodes in my example data) id values. My own feeble attempt:

//grandchild/parent::child/@id

returns:

```
text{"2"}, 
text{"3"}
```

only, but

```
text{"2"},
text{"2"}, 
text{"3"},
text{"3"}
```

is what I would like to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to use a host language to iterate over the `grandchild` elements and access `parent::child/@id` for each or you need to move to XPath 2.0 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-for-expressions) or later and use `for $gc in //grandchild return $gc/parent::child/@id` or to XPath 3.0 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-map-operator) or later and use `//grandchild!parent::child/@id`. With XPath any step `/exp` in a path selecting nodes eliminates duplicates so you can't write a single expression using `/` to return four `id` attributes for the two elements you have.

Comment: While the answer is technically correct, it does not explain why no duplicate can appear. XPath works on node-sets, not imperatively. The sets cannot contain duplicates by definition.

Comment: Well, if XPath operated solely on sets, my XPath 2.0 or 3.0 suggestions would not work. I explained that a step selecting nodes eliminates duplicates and that is correct in the sense of the XPath 2.0 and 3.0 data model and specifications. You are right that XPath 1.0 works on node sets.

Comment: Yes, I should have written that I meant XPath 1.0, thanks for pointing it out.